# How do you upgrade the building?

Tags: 10000000

I cannot buy another upgrade for my sword because it says the building is too low level.
So how do I further upgrade my building? All rooms have been built.

Comment: You should be able to upgrade rooms: http://steamcommunity.com/app/227580/discussions/0/846943418816247153/

Comment: @DavidStarkey Thanks, That button was easy to miss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to gather wood and stone, which will allow you to upgrade your rooms so you can upgrade further.  If I remember correctly, each room has 3 levels of upgrades.

The upgrade button, which is easy to miss, is to be found on the top right corner of the shop window:

[image: Where to find the upgrade button]

Comment: I added a picture where to find the upgrade button since that was the root of my issue, not to grasp the concept of getting wood and stone.

Comment: @noneofyourbusiness no problem I was planning to do that later.  I'm at work so I can't get to the image.

Comment: "If I remember correctly, each room has 3 levels of upgrades." I believe the training room has 4 levels.